# How can I override a CDI bean in Quarkus for testing?

Tags: quarkus

I have a CDI bean like so:

```java
@Dependent
class Parser {

  String[] parse(String expression) {
     return expression.split("::");
  }
}
```

It gets injected into another bean like this:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
class ParserService {

  @Inject
  Parser parser;

  //...
}
```

What I want to do is continue to use `Parser` in my regular code, but I want to use a "mock" for testing purposes. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All that needs to be done in this case is to create bean in test directory that looks something like the following:

```java
@Alternative
@Priority(1)
@Singleton
class MockParser extends Parser {

    String[] parse(String expression) {
        // some other implementation
    }
}
```

Here `@Alternative` and `@Priority` are CDI annotations that Quarkus will use to determine that `MockParser` will be used instead of `Parser` (for tests only of course).

More details can be found in the extension author's [guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/extension-authors-guide).

**Note**: The use of `@Alternarive` and `@Priority` is not of course limited to test code only. They can be used in any situation that use "overriding" a bean.

Comment: It worked on our code too. Thanks