# Injecting a different bean during local development with Quarkus

Tags: cdi, quarkus

With Spring and Micronaut, there are very concise ways to inject a different bean depending on what environment/profile an application is running in. I'm trying to do the same with Quarkus.

I've read this post: https://quarkus.io/blog/quarkus-dependency-injection/. And the process is alluded to in this StackOverflow post: [How can I override a CDI bean in Quarkus for testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56119064/how-can-i-override-a-cdi-bean-in-quarkus-for-testing). That last post says, "create bean in test directory".

My problem is slightly different. I'd like to inject a bean when in "development". In production, I'd like the default bean injected. From the docs, I can't see a way to have the app make this distinction.

If I have a default class like this:

```
@DefaultBean
@ApplicationScoped
class ProdProvider : SomeProvider {}
```

And I want to override it like this:

```
@Alternative
@Priority(1)
class DevProvider : SomeProvider {}
```

How can I make this happen only in dev mode?

In one case, I have a credential provider class that sets up Google's PubSub emulator while in local development. In production, I use a class that implements the same interface, but a real credential provider. The particular case that led me to asking this question, though is a a class that implements one method:

```
@ApplicationScoped
class VaultLoginJwtProvider : LoginJwtProvider {
  @ConfigProperty(name = "vault.tokenPath")
  private val jwtPath: String? = null

  companion object {
    val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("VaultTokenProvider")
  }

  override fun getLoginJwt(): Optional<String> {
    logger.info("Using Vault Login JWT")

    return try {
      Optional.of(String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(jwtPath))).trim { it <= ' ' })
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      logger.error("Could not read vault token at $jwtPath")
      logger.error(e.printStackTrace().toString())
      Optional.empty()
    }
  }
}
```

That class is injected into another class via constructor injection:

```
@Singleton
class JwtServiceImpl(
  @RestClient val vaultClient: VaultClient,
  @Inject val loginJwtProvider: LoginJwtProvider
) {
  private var serviceJwt: String? = null

  companion object {
    val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("JwtServiceImpl")
  }

  private fun getLoginToken(): String? {
    val vaultLogin = VaultLogin(
      role = "user-service",
      jwt = loginJwtProvider.getLoginJwt().get()
    )

    val loginResponse = vaultClient.login(vaultLogin)

    return loginResponse.auth.clientToken
  }
}
```

I'd like to inject more of a "mock" class while in development that just returns a static string. I could use `ProfileManager.getActiveProfile()`, but that has me mixing development concerns into my logic. And I don't feel that that has any place in my compiled production code.

This is possible in Micronaut by using the annotation `@Requires(env = ["dev", "test"])`. I did briefly look at using `@Produces` but the Oracle EE docs seemed a little bit difficult for me to grasp. If that's the solution, I'll dig in.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish - can you enrich the question with your specific use case? I would guess that one solution could be using [configuration profiles](https://quarkus.io/guides/config#configuration-profiles) and, maybe, a producer. But knowing the exact problem might yield more interesting solutions.

Comment: You can use ProfileManager.getActiveProfile() to execute custom logic according to active profile.

Comment: I've updated my question with a bit more detail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In case anybody else comes across this, this is how to do it: https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#enabling-beans-for-quarkus-build-profile

For example:

```
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;

import com.oi1p.common.EmailSender;
import com.oi1p.common.ErrorEmailSender;
import com.oi1p.common.LogOnlyEmailSender;

import io.quarkus.arc.DefaultBean;
import io.quarkus.arc.profile.IfBuildProfile;

@ApplicationScoped
public class Producers {

  @Produces
  @IfBuildProfile("dev")
  public EmailSender logOnlyEmailSender() {
    return new LogOnlyEmailSender();
  }

  @Produces
  @DefaultBean
  public EmailSender errorEmailSender() {
    // TODO: implement a real email sender.  This one explodes when poked.
    return new ErrorEmailSender();
  }

}
```

Comment: This is a build time / compile time mechanism, what if we wanted something like this at runtime? i guess it goes against the fundamental design of quarkus producing lightweight microservices as this would mean packaging some redundant classes in that wouldn't be used along with the jar.

Comment: @zaf187 I'm curious what your use case is.  Do you want the production build to use different injected classes based on values in `application.properties`?  It seems pretty clear that different injected classes in dev vs. test vs. prod make sense, but I'm having a hard time thinking of a scenario where I'd want prod behavior to differ based on some runtime parameter.

Comment: so the use case is, i have a file loader that supposed to use either; REST or AWS S3, so i have a factory which produces one or the other impl. I have a service class which uses the file loader and i want to inject one or the other depending on which `mode` the user is running in. The same Jar should be capable of running in both modes.

Comment: Which mode the *user* is running in, as opposed to the system?  And you're not talking about separate installed instances of the same jar, in which case you could switch to one or the other with props.

That seems like an odd way to do things, but did you find a solution that wasn't as obvious as querying user state and then doing one or the other based on the result?

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to create the final bean on my own inside a [@javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/Provider.html). Not as elegant as [Micronaut @Requires](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/context/annotation/Requires.html), but well, it works.

Note that instance of *SomeProvider* is not a "bean", you have to care for the lifecycle on your own (dependency injection, PostConstruct, no PreDestroy, ...).

**org.acme.SomeProvider.java**

```
package org.acme;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

public interface SomeProvider {

  void providerMethod();

  @ApplicationScoped
  class ProdProviderRequirement {
    void foo() {}
  }

  class ProdProvider implements SomeProvider {

    private final ProdProviderRequirement prodProviderRequirement;

    ProdProvider(final ProdProviderRequirement prodProviderRequirement) {
      this.prodProviderRequirement = prodProviderRequirement;
    }

    @Override
    public void providerMethod() {
      prodProviderRequirement.foo();
    }
  }

  class DevProvider implements SomeProvider {
    @Override
    public void providerMethod() {}
  }
}
```

**org.acme.SomeProviderFactory.java**

```
package org.acme;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import org.acme.SomeProvider.DevProvider;
import org.acme.SomeProvider.ProdProvider;
import org.acme.SomeProvider.ProdProviderRequirement;

@Provider
class SomeProviderFactory {

  SomeProvider someProvider;

  @Inject
  SomeProviderFactory(final ProdProviderRequirement prodProviderRequirement) {
    final var someCondition = true;
    someProvider = someCondition ? new DevProvider() : new ProdProvider(prodProviderRequirement);
  }

  @Produces
  @ApplicationScoped
  SomeProvider someProvider() {
    return someProvider;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is basically what we ended up doing. I'm not keen on including so much development only stuff in my prod code. But this works. Thank you very much for the response.